# A problematic function for my chess app I built in react.js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was hoping I can get some tips with a certain function in my chess app. The function tracks if the path for the selected piece is clear or not. The problem I have is that it doesn't seem to quite work. An example would be the rook being able to kill the other rook on the first move of the game, completely ignoring every other piece in it's path. I tried using the reduce method, but to no avail.

Here is my code for the function:

```
const isPathClean = (srcToDestPath, squares) => {
    return  srcToDestPath.reduce((acc, curr) => acc && !squares[curr], true);
   }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - _"Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"_,, _"**Describe the problem**. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question."_

Comment: What is `srcToDestPath` here? Are you sure it's correct? What about `squares`?

Comment: srcToDestPath is short for source to destination path while squares is the individual arrays that play the role of the squares on the chessboard. Imagine it as a sort of array matrix consisting of 64 arrays or "squares". The source is the starting array of the piece and the destination is the array toward which it is headed. That's the functionality of the piece movement. What I'm looking for in particular is a way to integrate unit collision so to speak. Let's say if my pawn is in front of my rook, my rook should't be able to jump over it as it is now. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for something like

```
const isPathClean = (srcToDestPath, squares) => {
  // `.some` returns true if the predicate is true
  // for any member of the array, i.e. if any of the
  // squares on the path is taken.
  // The outer `!` negates that, so this returns true
  // if the path is clear.
  return !srcToDestPath.some(p => squares[p]);
}
```

but it's really rather hard to tell based on your question.

Comment: _"but it's really rather hard to tell based on your question"_ - Then ask for clarification and don't add a guess as an answer o.O

Comment: @Andreas I've found that educated guesses tend to help more than trying to pry for details in a comment thread that inevitably ends up in "avoid extended discussions".

Comment: Unfortunately this function yields the same results as my own, as for the clarification please tell me what you want to know in particular and I'll be sure to respond.